# Is Magento 2 use both EAV and Flat?

Tags: magento2

I had read an article about Flat and EAV. However, I don't understand much about it in Magento 2. Is Magento 2 also use both EAV and Flat? Or just only EAV? And what for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses EAV to define and store product, category, customer and customer address attributes.

This allows great flexibility, e.g. making it easy to add attributes without modifying core tables.

However, this flexibility comes with a performance cost when querying the database. A query that includes multiple attributes requires separate joins for each.

To remedy this problem, Magento optionally stores product and category attributes in "flat" tables. It is possible to configure which attributes are included. The "flat" tables are updated by Magento's indexing process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes magento2 uses both EAV and Flat and for example products and categories you can change from EAV to flat by go to below admin configuration

**Store > Configuration > Catalog > Storefront > Use Flat Catalog Category or Use Flat Catalog Product = YES:**

and after that run indexing using below command

> php bin/magento index:reindex